# How can I group the results of a many-to-many via sql as opposed to using php to do so?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a many-to-many relationship between "projects" and "participants".  One project can have many participants, and one participant can have many projects.  Lets say that John has 3 projects.  When I execute the sql with join, I get 3 rows, one row for each of Johns' projects.  While this is the data that I want, in the view (MVC), I only want to display John 1 time, and there is a field on the view for Johns' projects where I want to display all 3 of johns projects.  Is there a sql way to bunch those projects together, or do I have to do that with some logic similar to:

```
pseudo-code 
userid=null;  //to make sure that i am grouping only one users' projects
projectname = null;  //will be appended to in each iteration of loop
foreach( row_in_resultset as row )
{

   projectname += " " + row->projectname;
   if( this_is_a_different_userid )
   {
      projectname = "";  //reset the project name
   }

}
```

The above code is just a quick brain dump, but hopefully it is clear that for each participant, I want an end result of 1 participant object like this

```
participant
{
   name = john smith
   address = 100 foobar street
   projects = paint house, feed cat, do stuff

}
```

as opposed to what I'm currently getting, which is

```
participant
{
   name = john smith
   address = 100 foobar street
   projects = paint house

}


participant
{
   name = john smith
   address = 100 foobar street
   projects = feed cat

}


participant
{
   name = john smith
   address = 100 foobar street
   projects = do stuff

}
```

This seems like a pretty basic question, and in the past I would have just done it already.  But I'm looking for a possible better way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use mysql GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT method

```
SELECT 
    users.username, users.address, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(projects SEPARATOR ', ') AS projects
FROM
    users JOIN projects_to_users 
        ON users.user_id = projects_to_users.user_id
    JOIN projects
        ON projects_to_users.project_id = projects.project_id
GROUP BY
    users.user_id;
```

Hope this explains it :)

Comment: exactly what I am looking for.  I am now wrestling with the syntax, but this is the concept I was looking for.  thank you!

Comment: Got the syntax now!  This is a very useful piece of knowledge!